# How do I arrange a project with .Net Core 2.0 MVC, Web API and AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-core

I want to build up a project with .NET Core 2.0 MVC with Web API. And for JS I want to use Angular 4. Is it possible to make it in one project. Or I have to create two different project one for MVC and another for API? Can anyone help me out for explain the whole process that I have to do. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Core MVC, Web API and Angular can coexist inside the same project.

If you start your project using an MVC or Web API project template then you may just need to add the necessary dependencies to the project for the ASP.NET feature (MVC or Web API) that is missing. Personally I would just create a Web API project from a template and a separate MVC project from template and merge the configurations as necessary. Angular will be your client-side piece that complements your MVC and Web API controllers and thus can be packaged in the same project as well.

If you are using VS 2017 for development there is an Angular project template that will give you a sample project that is already setup to support both MVC and Web API development. It will also come with some sample Angular code. Here is an article that may assist with usage of the VS Angular template:

https://medium.com/@levifuller/building-an-angular-application-with-asp-net-core-in-visual-studio-2017-visualized-f4b163830eaa

Comment: So, at first I will add API template. Then add another project MVC. That's clear. But after that I have to add another project Angular?

Comment: I would suggest using the VS 2017 Angular template if it's available. That template will contain all the MVC, Web API and Angular infrastructure without the need to merge the individual configurations manually.